# How to include files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a few custom php pages in wordpress. I know that a page like this can be done by creating a Wp page template.

However my script has two files: index.php and register_for_event.php.

Index.php contains this:

```
<form action='register_for_event.php' method='post'>
```

So now I have to create a template page for register_for_event.php as well? That page only registers the user in the database and echos 'thank you'. Besides these two files I have at least 30 other php pages. All of them need a new page template?

Comment: 1st question is, where do you put the PHP, inside the theme or, the root of WordPress or outside WordPress?

Comment: inside the theme, but I could put it anywhere.

Comment: Do your form post target PHP ( `register_for_event.php` ) require to use WordPress functions ?

Comment: No. It's a simple php form.

Comment: For simple form, you can put it at the root of WordPress and use the path you wrote in the question. Alternatively, you can follow @Farrukh's answer to follow WP's traits.

Comment: Great thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should need this, [Access WordPress functions in a different php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058957/access-wordpress-functions-in-a-different-php-file)

- In your register_for_event.php call following line,

require('PATH_TO/wp-blog-header.php');

- Receive your values from index.php by $_POST
- Use wp_create_user function - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. require('.././wp-blog-header.php'); worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use it with wordpress culture and create a page that submits action to wp-admin or another page and then put your php in another page with page template. So for both pages create two page templates.

1. Template for index page and have all its PHP and code in there
2. Template for register for event page with all php script in there.
3. Create two pages with each using one of these templates and give them a url.
4. Regardless of template look or content on page the PHP script would run. You need to change form action to /register-event/ or whatever your page url is after you have

The concept is same your script uses post back to post to register_for_event and post processing is done in PHP.

Ideally you can create a function in your theme that process the request with nonce sent with form and form created through with current nonce given to it on any page using short code etc. But above technique is sufficient as well.